# TileView like controls for HTML5

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to create some kind of control or if it exists a tile view control in jquery that is similar to this control http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TileView/FirstLook , the link of example is a silverlight control... but I need this control in jquery.

There is jquery Masonry but, is it possible to make controls like telerik's tileview?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQueryUI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

Comment: looks pretty, should i use the animations and properties to implement?

Comment: mskmeric, did you find anything like that?